# First record of the List, is not getting into the Map

Tags: apex, map

I am writing a logic, where I am storing a List`mpgList` into a Map `discountMap`.

But, inside the map, 1st record of List isn't getting an entry into Map. So any help??

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Material_Price_Group__c>>> discountMap =
 new Map<String, Map<String, List<Material_Price_Group__c>>>(); 
// String = MPG Code , String = current/future

 List<Material_Price_Group__c > mpgList = [Select Id,                                                      
                                                     MPG_Code__c, 
                                                     End_Date__c, 
                                                     Effective_Date__c, 
                                                     Discount_Percent__c 
                                                     From Material_Price_Group__c 
                                                     where End_Date__c >= TODAY
                                                     order by Effective_Date__c];

  system.debug('DEBUG: ---mpgList '+mpgList );//This mpgList  giving me 3 records



            for(Material_Price_Group__c mpg : mpgList) {

                if(mpg.End_Date__c < system.today()) {
                    continue;   
                }
                string mpgCode = mpg.MPG_Code__c;

                string timeFrame = (mpg.Effective_Date__c <= system.today() && mpg.End_Date__c >= system.today() ? CURRENT : FUTURE);

                Map<String, List<Material_Price_Group__c>> innerMap = new Map<String, List<Material_Price_Group__c>>();

                if(discountMap.containsKey(mpgCode)) {
                    innerMap = discountMap.get(mpgCode);
                } else {
                    discountMap.put(mpgCode, innerMap);
                }

                if(!innerMap.containsKey(timeFrame)) {
                    innerMap.put(timeFrame, new List<Material_Price_Group__c>());   
                } else {
                    innerMap.get(timeFrame).add(mpg);
                }
            }

            system.debug('DEBUG:**discountMap'+discountMap); // All 3 records are satisfying the above condition, but still discountMap is storing 2 records. First record isn't getting stored in this map.

        }
```

This is the logic, I thought would work. But it didn't, so any help so that all the satisfied records will get into the Map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually adding the first item to the list.

```
innerMap.put(timeFrame, new List<Material_Price_Group__c>());
```

Should be:

```
innerMap.put(timeFrame, new List<Material_Price_Group__c>{ mpg });
```